# How to customize height of first and second level of TLN - SAP Netweaver 7.3

Tags: netweaver

We removed pictures from TLN, but is it still too big. I need to know how to change height of TLN. Thx you lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i remember the 7.3 display, the overflow area (the < and > button to select non visible tabs from the TLN)  take some vertical space, and thus limit the minimum size of the TLN.

There is a document [here](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/a03ead25-4288-2e10-57ae-c70b8c412629?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&51552492524959) with the description of the customization of portal theme for 7.3. It seems the overflow area takes 63 or 42 pixels pixels by default (depending on TLN with or without pictures)

regards.